# DOORS DXL: Insert string in XML file on specific location

Tags: xml, file, ibm-doors

I try to fill up an XML file.
I open the file, and i would like to insert a string into a specific position of the file.

Is there any possibility without reading the whole content, 
and manipulating the buffer and then overwrite the old file?
It is necessary to write a lot of new tags, so i would avoid this method,
and write just the new tags directly to their specific position.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance,
hb

Comment: The way you described is the only method available. There is no built in XML DOM Parser in DXL. You have to read the whole file in, search for the tags or locations you want to add text and then write them back to the same or a new file.

Comment: Thanks! I have to find another solution.

Comment: @SteveValliere please answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The way you described is the only method available. There is no built in XML DOM Parser in DXL. You have to read the whole file in, search for the tags or locations you want to add text and then write them back to the same or a new file.